# how to remove all markers and polyline from google map in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I had already try to use `googleMap.remove()` and `route.remove()` it will remove everything but when I recreate it it will show double markers. How can I remove all markers and polyline and recreate markers and polyline in Android?

Comment: You can check my solution

Answer (score 2):

You clear googleMap and old data list, Example

```
googleMap.clear();
markerList.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing `polyline.setMap(null)`, which will remove the lines from the google map and please find the below documentation for more clarification:

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Polyline